# How to get values from a PHP file querying MongoDB in jQuery's getJSON()?

Tags: php, jquery, mongodb, getjson

I am learning MongoDB and hoped that because data stored in MongoDB databases was in a format very similar to JSON I would be able to query MongoDB directly from jQuery's `getJSON()` method.

I am learning however that it seems you need MongoDB and a `driver` to access the database from an application.  So I am going with the PHP driver for the time being.

I am trying to return the `value` of the `content` field:

**MongoDB Document**

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("34576347347"),
   "content": "here is some content",
   "field2": {
     "subfield1": {
       "0": "sf1v0",
       "1": "sf1v1",
       "2": "sf1v2" 
    },
     "subfield2": "value 2" 
  },
   "field2": "value 3" 
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 

$dbhost = 'username:password@127.x.xx.x:27017/';
$dbname = 'dbname';
$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://$dbhost");
$db = $m->$dbname;
$collection = $db->myCollection;
$query = $collection->find(array("field2.subfield2" => "value 2"));

header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($query);

?>
```

**jQuery**

```
$.getJSON("http://path/to/mongo.php", {cid: href, format: 'json'}, function(results){  
$("#my_div").html(results[0].content);
}
```

I think I need to 'get' a few things:

1. What is being returned from the PHP query:

   ```
   $query = $collection->find(array("field2.subfield2" => "value 2"));
   ```

   I think the MongoDB terminology it that it is returning the `cursor`, but is that a PHP array, or JSON data or something else?
2. What is the correct 'call' to make in the `getJSON()` code to return the required data?

   At the moment Firebug is showing me:

   ```
   TypeError: results[0] is undefined
   ```

**Update**

I changed `getJSON()` code to:

```
$("#my_div").html(results.content);
```

And now I don't get an error, but the following from Firebug:

> Response tab shows:  {}
>
> JSON tab shows:  There are no properties to show for this object.

Answer (score 2):

You want to convert the cursor returned from the `find()` function to something json_encode can actually use like so:

```
$cursor = $collection->find(array("field2.subfield2" => "value 2"));
echo json_encode(iterator_to_array($cursor, false));
```

This is because the query is not run until you iterate the cursor. Iterator_to_array basically will exhaust the cursor, get all documents, and put them into an array for json_encode.

#### Edit

Specifying `false` as the second `$use_keys` argument to `iterator_to_array()` will ensure that the results are indexed numerically (instead of by the `_id` field of each document).

Comment: I added a note about `iterator_to_array()`'s `$use_keys` argument. That should be more efficient than running the results through `array_values()`, and also avoids exceptions when a document `_id` is an embedded object, which can't be used as an array index.